# Converting SPA to Subdirectory Structure

Tags: javascript, php, web, single-page-application

I'm running a site that operates like a blog, with a main splash page and then linked content, where the content template is always the same. Because only the data changes from post to post, I originally created the site as an SPA, with JavaScript generating most of the DOM elements and injecting them into the templates; however, my understanding is that this is deleterious to SEO results (although I've read about this for hours and it seems like there's still a lot of disagreement?).

I'm considering converting the site to a multi-page app, replacing structures like:

`www.mysite.com/#post-181`

with:

`www.mysite.com/post-181`

In other words, what was formerly dynamically served via a look at the URL hash will now live in a persistent subdirectory whose `index.php` will serve the content. My question is: What is the usual best practice for formulating these paths when new content is created? Do I need to create the subdirectory each time I create a new post, or are there methods (outside of using a CMS) for setting up this structure and having it automatically update? I loved that the SPA required only updates to the data in order to update the site, so I'm hoping a similar solution might exist in a more traditional link structure.

I'm happy to provide clarification if there's anything I've left out, and if I'm misunderstanding the SEO issue, I'd love to hear a correct analysis.

Comment: You can have PHP automatically generate the directories along with the post's html file

Comment: Can you point me toward a tutorial or some reading on this method?

Comment: it's really just the [`mkdir()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) function you need to look at

Comment: I see - so is the idea that I would write a PHP script to examine the data, determine the necessary folder structure, and create it; then, run the script each time the data is updated?

Comment: If you change the URL of the post, you'd have to change the directory name, otherwise, you can just update the index.html / index.php that is serving the posts content